# How can I make a logout button in Rails without using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a Rails application without using any Javascript, and I am wondering how I can implement a logout button to set a session to "nil". Most tutorials suggest using "method: :delete", however that requires the use of JavaScript.

Session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new

  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:name])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/posts'
    else
      session[:user_id] = nil
      flash[:warning] = "Failed login- try again"
      redirect_to '/login'
    end 
  end

  def destroy
    session[:session_id] = nil 
    redirect_to login_path 
  end
end
```

Comment: _“suggest using `method: :delete`, however that requires the use of JavaScript”_ —not at all. Use plain HTML `<form action="..." method="delete">`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `button_to` instead of `link_to`.

```
<%= button_to logout_path, method: :destroy %>
```

`button_to` actually creates a discrete `<form>` element and thus works perfectly fine even without javascript. `method: :destroy` adds a hidden input which is used by `Rack::MethodOverride`.

When signing a user out you should reset the session and not just remove the user id from the session storage.

```
def destroy
  reset_session
  redirect_to login_path 
end
```

This invalidates the entire session storage cookie and [prevents session fixation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-fixation-countermeasures). Better yet is not reinventing the authentication wheel in the first place.